# Get a list of file types that can be opened with a specific application

Tags: bash

In Ubuntu, is there any way to obtain a list of file types that can be opened with a specific application? For example, I'd like to find a list of all files that can be opened with the program `google-chrome`. Is it possible to do this using a shell script?

Comment: Also, it's possible to get a list of applications that can be used to open a file (basically the inverse of this.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395471/python-get-list-of-applications-associated-with-file-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look in /usr/share/applications/defaults.list to see a list of file types and their associated apps.

For a specific app, type this into your terminal:

```
grep "google-chrome" /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

You'll see something like this:

```
text/html=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
text/xml=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
application/xhtml_xml=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=google-chrome.desktop
```

Comment: This looks useful. How can I obtain the file extension for each file type?

Comment: The application to open is not determined by the extension but by the mimetype, like `text/html`. Doing `cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` will get you many file types. Also have a look at Ubuntu Tweak which is great for viewing adding file type  associations

Comment: @AndersonGreen Some of the file associations are also stored in your home folder: `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.